# not a function error for imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

This might be a simple reference/binding error, but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
import React from 'react';
var { View, StyleSheet, Alert, AsyncStorage } = require('react-native');

import {Button} from 'react-native-elements'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import styles from "./styles"

import { actions as auth} from "../../../auth/index"
import { actions as home } from "../../index";
import { user } from '../../../auth/scenes/Login/index';

const { getToken } = home;
const { signOut } = auth;

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { }

    this.onSignOut = this.onSignOut.bind(this);
    this.onShowData = this.onShowData.bind(this);
}

onSignOut() {
    this.props.signOut(this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this))
}

onSuccess() {
    Actions.reset("Auth")
}

onError(error) {
    Alert.alert('Oops!', error.message);
}

onShowData(){
 AsyncStorage.getItem("userData").then((value) => {
   this.props.getToken(value); //THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR
   alert(value);
   Actions.pop();
 });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                raised
                borderRadius={4}
                title={'LOG OUT'}
                containerViewStyle={[styles.containerView]}
                buttonStyle={[styles.button]}
                textStyle={styles.buttonText}
                onPress={this.onSignOut}/>
              <Button
                borderRadius={4}
                title={'Show Data'}
                containerViewStyle={[styles.showDataButton]}
                buttonStyle={[styles.button]}
                textStyle={styles.buttonText}
                onPress={this.onShowData}/>
        </View>
    );
}
}

export default connect(null, { signOut })(Home);
```

The weird thing is, signOut was read properly from auth, which is an import from acions.js of auth folder. However, the getToken function is not recognized from home, which is an action.js import from home foler.
I did both exactly the same way and have checked all references to these js files, directories, as well as function exports.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a map to your `getToken`, as you are doing for `signOut`:

```
export default connect(null, { signOut, getToken })(Home);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^-- added this
```

This way `this.props.getToken` should be available inside `Home`.

Comment: ahhh right I totally forgot about that! thanks heaps!